# Looking for Schach Ideas

Tags: how-to, sukkah, schach

I have a bit of unique situation. I have a nice sized outdoor space (I live in a basement apartment) in an urban area and wanted to put up a sukkah. I have large walls on every side of the space and just need to find a way to put up schach. There is no obvious way to rest anything on top of the walls. So I need to support and put up schach. I had a few ideas but none have been able to work.

1. cotton netting and putting twigs on top.

-problem: Strong enough to support the wood.

2. Cotton/linnen bug netting

-problem hishataneh and therefore pasul mi'derabanan.

3. Raw Cotton.

-problem: expensive and will blow away.

Looking for (hopefully budget friendly) ideas. Okay with ma'amid if need be.

Comment: what are the approximate dimensions of the sukka?

Comment: You may be able to rest walls against the outside walls and put schach on top of them

Comment: @Tesvov 8ft tall walls 8ft wide and can be flexible in terms of lenght

Answer (score 1):

I use bamboo poles to hold up the main schach. They are lightweight, but very sturdy. In addition, they are kosher for schach, so no problem of maamid.

Answer (score 0):

You can rest some 2x4s on top of the walls and put leafy tree branches like evergreen, bamboo, or similar across the 2x4s.

If resting 2x4 on top of the walls is not an option, you can use these to attach 2x4s to the walls: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-LUS-ZMAX-Galvanized-Face-Mount-Joist-Hanger-for-2x4-Nominal-Lumber-LUS24Z/100375190